# How do I combine two if statements in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I combine the two sets of if statements below in Swift? I've looked at some of the examples but just can't wrap my head around how to do it in my code. I need help from someone a lot smarter in Swift than me.

```
if searching {
    return searchMaterial.count
} else {
    return materialData.count
}

if isFavorite == true {
    return favoritesData.count
} else {
    return materialData.count
}
```

And...

```
if searching {
    cell.textLabel?.text = searchMaterial[indexPath.row]
} else {
    cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]
}

if isFavorite == true {
    cell.textLabel?.text = favoritesData[indexPath.row]
} else {
    cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]
}

return cell
```

Comment: Do you want to combine searching and isFavorite statements or both searching and both isFavorite statements?

Comment: I'm not really sure I have the vocabulary to explain it correctly, but I can't just so an if else, because there are are situations where the user will be searching and adding an tableview item to favoritesData. Or no searching and add an item to favoritesData. Or searching and not adding an item to favoritesData and in that case returning materialData. I know that's terrible explanation, but bottomline, it's not an either or so I need to have all possible combinations covered.

Comment: Your problem is the data structure. Please, show us how you generate `favoritesData` and `searchMaterial`. Probably this should be done completely different.

Comment: This is how I populate searchMaterial within the UISearchBar func: searchMaterial = materialData.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText}). materialData is my array. favoritesData is populated with what I posted in my first block of code in the OP via the if searching statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intension is to reduce code complexity, then you can also try the Ternary Operator? You will end up writing 4 lines of code.

```
let searchMaterialcount = searching ? searchMaterial.count : materialData.count
let favouriteMaterialcount = isFavorite ? favoritesData.count : materialData.count
```

AND

```
searching ? (cell.textLabel?.text = searchMaterial[indexPath.row]) : (cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]);
isFavorite ? (cell.textLabel?.text = favoritesData[indexPath.row]) : (cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AND statement here like:-

```
if searching == true && isFavorite == true {


cell.textLabel?.text = searchMaterial[indexPath.row]


cell.textLabel?.text = favoritesData[indexPath.row]

} else {


cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]


cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]
}
```

But this is not valid for the condition when one of the two, searching or favorite is the true and the second one is false. For that we can write it like:-

```
if searching == true && isFavorite == true {


cell.textLabel?.text = searchMaterial[indexPath.row]


cell.textLabel?.text = favoritesData[indexPath.row]
} else if  searching == true{
cell.textLabel?.text = searchMaterial[indexPath.row]
} else if isFavorite == true{
cell.textLabel?.text = favoritesData[indexPath.row]
}
else {


cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]


ell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use enums, if you have 2 or more options true-false;

```
enum situation {
   case searching
   case isfavorite
   case material
}

var labelText = ""

switch situation {
   case .searching:
         labelText = searchMaterial[indexPath.row]
   case .isFavorite:
         labelText = favoritesData[indexPath.row]
   default:
         labelText = materialData[indexPath.row]
}

cell.textLabel?.text = labelText
```